# Unity3d equivalent of ACRA Android crash reporter library

Tags: reporting, game-development

Is there a Unity3d equivalent of [Android ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) crash reporter library that one can use? ACRA saves the crash reports if not connected to the internet and can use a variety of ways to send the crashes(stack trace) to your backend of choice.

The furthest I got was hook into the `Application.logMessageReceived` [callback](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html).

Also we are not interested in using 3rd party specialised crash reporting services as we are building our own service for doing this. We just need a way of catching the errors(stack trace) and sending them or storing them for later delivery when internet connection is available.